# htaccess redirect dynamic get request

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, get

I need to REDIRECT (not just rewrite) from:

```
example.com/home/?s=keyword
```

to:

```
example.com/search/keyword
```

Currently I am trying to use the following:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/www\.example\.com\/home\/" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^/s=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*?)$ search/$1 [NC,R,L]
```

I know it is wrong but I have no idea how to fix it...

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://www.example.com/home/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+home/?\?s=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^home/?$ /search/%1? [L,R]

RewriteRule ^search/(.+)$ /home/?s=$1 [L]
```

Comment: The last line is not relevant, I don't need anything to be rewriten, only redirected with the variable in the get. How can I make it work? (It gives 404 right now)

Comment: @Sinros going to `/search/keyword` gives you 404? Because there's nothing there.

Comment: `/search/keyword` works without rules, it shows results for `keyword` what I need is to redireect the request at `/home/?s=abc` so it will become `/search/abc`

Comment: @Sinros that's what the second rule does